# How to set background on the selected item in the quick launch left menu?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, quick-launch

I am using sharepoint 2013 online (o365). I am using sharepoint designer and has added my custom css. I have add some styling and they are working. Now I would like to style the left menu (quick launch). I would like to set the background color of the selected item. In the source I found this class and set it in my custom css. But it dont work. What do I need to do?

```
 .static selected menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-core-listMenu-selected ms-navedit-linkNode 
 {
         background-color:red !important;
 }
```

Comment: try this : `.ms-core-sideNavBox-removeLeftMargin .ms-core-listMenu-selected{background-color : red !important;}`

Answer (score 2):

Opening SharePoint 2013 Online (O365) site page using `developer tool` or in `SP Designer` check the master page, we can observe that the html of `Left Navigation` is rendered under `Div` with id `sideNavBox`.

**Developer Tool Screen Shot**

[image]

**SPD screen shot**

[image]

So in order to change `background colour` of `Left Nav` selected link, I would recommend below `css class`

```
div#sideNavBox li.selected > a {
  background-color: red;
}
```

If your `custom.css` is getting rendered before `corev15.css` then I guess you don't need to add `!important` hack, Otherwise use below.

```
div#sideNavBox li.selected > a {
  background-color: red!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This css worked for me, I used this in CEWP on SharePoint 2013 on premise.

Try this css code:

```
<style>
.ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox UL.root > LI > .menu-item {
     /*Style each menu item*/
     background-color: red;
}
.ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox > ul.root > li.static > ul.static > li.static > a:hover {
     /*Style on hove sub items*/
      background-color: blue;
}
.ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox > ul.root > li.selected > a { 
     /*Style selected top level item*/
      background-color: yellow;
}
.ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox > ul.root > li > a:hover {  
     /*Style top level mouse hover*/
      background-color: green;
</style>
```

[image]

Further you can use css according to your need.

Answer (score -1):

```
.sideNavBox .menu-item.selected{
 background-color:red !important;}
```

or

```
#sideNavBox .menu-item.selected{
 background-color:red !important;}
```